# Log4j RollingFileAppender not rolling in Apache tomcat (windows)

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, logback, rollingfileappender

I have a problem with the rolling the logs in apache tomcat.
[ In my war webapp ]
This is my log handler configuration:

```
    private static final String logLayoutStr = "[%-20t][%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%-40.40c{2}]: [%-5p] %m%n";

   public static String LOG_FILE_PATH = "log file path";
   private static final Integer MAX_BACKUP_INDEX = 200;
   private static final String MAX_FILE_SIZE = "50MB";

   public LogHandler() {
       Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN);

      try {
          addAppenderToLogger(mainLogger, logLayoutStr, LOG_FILE_PATH);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  }

   private void addAppenderToLogger (Logger l, String layout, String path)    throws IOException {
      RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(new    EnhancedPatternLayout(layout), path, true);
      rollingFileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(MAX_BACKUP_INDEX);
      rollingFileAppender.setMaxFileSize(MAX_FILE_SIZE);

      //we wrap each rolling appender with an async appender
      AsyncAppender asyncAppender = new AsyncAppender();
      asyncAppender.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
      l.addAppender(asyncAppender);
      l.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
  }
```

I want to mention that on linux servers in Apache tomcat there is no problem of rolling.
In Windows servers, the file just increasing without any rolling.

I can give a simple example for usage :

I have log file, that exceeding 50 MB -> should conver to log.1 and a new log file should be opened for writing.

When I stop the tomcat service, and change the log extention to log.1 (after the file is too big) then a new log file is opened (after starting tomcat service again).

When the new file reaches it max (50 MB), the log.1 file is being renamed to log.2, but the log file is still increasing and not changing to log.1 and creating new log file.

Can you please advise ?

Comment: Earlier there were some issues with Log4J, RollingAppenders and Windows. Which version do you use?

Comment: Log4j is not under active development anymore. Try using Logback : )

Comment: I'm using 1.2.17 version